# how to set a value of 'P' in php date function

Tags: php

I have this value +05:00
this is my code

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date('H:i A P');
```

how can i set P to be +05:00

Comment: simply i want to display the time in +05:00 zone but using only the value not string as 'UTC',.. etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`P` is the difference between the current timezone and UTC. If you set the timezone to UTC, you'll naturally have a difference of zero. Try:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT-5');
echo date('H:i A P');
```

Note that in most cases, you don't want a fixed difference from UTC, but instead the local timezone in a country or region. You should pick your local timezone (for example, mine is `Europe/Berlin`) out of the [list of supported timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php), and configure that in your application or [`php.ini`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.configuration.php#ini.date.timezone).

Comment: i just know the difference hours like +05:00 not 'Etc/GMT-5'

Comment: For +5 hours, use 'Asia/Yekaterinburg', however this is the correct method.

Comment: @Bilal Sorry, I don't follow. I just told you about Etc/GMT-5, so you know it now, don't you? If you have the difference in an integer (so your input is like `$diffHours = 5`), you can simply pick `'Etc/GMT-' . (-$diffHours)`.

Comment: @Dickie Using `Asia/Yekaterinburg` is *not* correct if you always want a difference of 5 hours. Local laws [change](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-reduces-time-zones.html) often.

Comment: @phihag I have a banner on which I want to show local time.
how can I do this? just simple.

Comment: @phihag I am currrently using geobytes api to find the location and it returns me an array having only difference hours of physical location

Comment: @Bilal If the hours are always round, you can pick `'Etc/GMT-' . (-$diffHours)`. Otherwise, you'll have to create a new [`DateTimeZone`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) object yourself.

Comment: @philang I apologise. I mis-read your questions as you wanted +5 from UTC.